# google structured data availability not showing in google

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I have configured a **Structured Data** for a Product. Although each itemprop was showing up no errors in **Google structured data Testing tool**, But in google I couldn't see the price and availability. Same link in google .

I have followed the google documentation. For the [Product](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product) Example  coded like this ( I just replaced the value with some static values for simplicity) :

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <h2 itemprop="name">Product Name</h2>
    <p itemprop="description">descriptiondescriptiondescription</p>
    <link itemprop="image" content="banner.jpg" alt="altdescription">
    <meta itemprop="sku" content="skudescription">
    <meta itemprop="mpn" content="mpndescription">
    <span itemprop="Brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="xxx.com"/>
    </span>
    <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer"/>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="39"/>
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR"/>
        <meta itemprop="lowPrice" content="49"/>
        <meta itemprop="highPrice" content="249"/>
        <meta itemprop="offerCount" content="20"/>
    </span>
        <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.9"/>
        <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="37" />
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">
        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
    </span>
    <span itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"/>
        <meta itemprop="author" content="xxx xxxx"/>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="xxx xxx"/>
        <meta itemprop="description" content="reviewdescription"/>
    </span>
        <span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"/>
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.9"/>
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">
        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
    </span>
    <div class="table-responsive" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">                             
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td itemprop="name">product-name</td>
                <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
                <td itemprop="price"><span class="start-amount">&euro; 49.00</span></td>
                <td itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"><a href="#" class="get-free-quote">Order Now</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried `ld+Json` format as follow

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "description": "description",
    "name": "namey",
    "image": "/logo.png",
    "sku": "sku-name",
    "mpn": "mpn-name",
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4.7",
        "reviewCount": "36"
    },
    "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": "xxx.com"
    },
    "offers": {
        "@type": "AggregateOffer",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
        "price": "39",
        "priceCurrency": "EUR",
        "lowPrice": "39",
        "highPrice": "279",
        "offerCount": "11",
        "priceValidUntil": "31-07-2020",
        "url": "url-site/dummy/"
    },
    "review": [
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": "xxx xxx",
            "datePublished": "2019-04-20",
            "description": "review-description",
            "name": "xxx xxxx",
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "bestRating": "5",
                "ratingValue": "5",
                "worstRating": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">{
   "@context":"http://schema.org",
   "@type":"Organization",
   "image":"/logo.png",
   "name": "org-name",
   "address":{
      "@type":"PostalAddress",
       "streetAddress": "address",
       "addressLocality": "city,
       "addressRegion": "state",
       "postalCode": "000000",
       "addressCountry": "usa"
   },
   "url": "url-site",
   "telephone": "+001-00 00 00 0000"
}</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">{
   "@context":"http://schema.org",
   "@type":"Organization",
   "name": "org-name",
   "url": "url-site",
   "sameAs":[
      "https://www.facebook.com/xxxt",
      "https://twitter.com/xxx"
   ]
}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">{
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "url-site",
      "logo": "/logo.png",
      "contactPoint": [{
   "@type": "ContactPoint",
      "telephone": "+001-00 00 00 0000",
      "contactType": "customer service"
      }
   ]
}</script>
```

Comment: Can you specify the google in your question like **Google Structured Data testing Tool, Google Search, Google search console** because every where google is not specifying the exact words. it a bit confusing what is happening and where

Comment: you can define address, links in same u don't have to write different Scripts for address, contact point, sameAs, etc.

Comment: Like ` `<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Organization","image":"/logo.png","name":"org-name","url":"url-site","sameAs":["https://www.facebook.com/xxxt","https://twitter.com/xxx"],"telephone":"+001-00 00 00 0000","contactPoint":[{"@type":"ContactPoint","telephone":"+001-00 00 00 0000","contactType":"customer service"}],"address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","streetAddress":"148 W 51st St","addressLocality":"New York","addressRegion":"NY","postalCode":"10019","addressCountry":"US"}}</script>`

Comment: It is showing in Google Structured Data testing Tool but not in Google Search and Google search console. I have waited almost 25 days to reflect changes.

Thanks i have updated above code related to address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your html example you need to place the Offer inside the offers span. At the moment it is out on its own.

For the json-ld example the issue may be that you place the availability in the AggregateOffer. Google may only support it in Offer, which is missing.

```html
 <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <h2 itemprop="name">Product Name</h2>
    <p itemprop="description">descriptiondescriptiondescription</p>
    <link itemprop="image" content="banner.jpg" alt="altdescription"/>
    <meta itemprop="sku" content="skudescription"/>
    <meta itemprop="mpn" content="mpndescription"/>
    <div itemprop="Brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="xxx.com"/>
    </div>
    <div  itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer">
        <meta itemprop="price" content="39"/>
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR"/>
        <meta itemprop="lowPrice" content="49"/>
        <meta itemprop="highPrice" content="249"/>
        <meta itemprop="offerCount" content="20"/>
        <div itemprop="offers"class="table-responsive" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">                             
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td itemprop="name">product-name</td>
                    
                    <td><meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" /><span class="start-amount"  itemprop="price" content="49.00">&euro; 49.00</span></td>
                    <td><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/><a href="#" class="get-free-quote">Order Now</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.9"/>
        <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="37" />
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5"/>
        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1"/>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
        <meta itemprop="author" content="xxx xxxx"/>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="xxx xxx"/>
        <meta itemprop="description" content="reviewdescription"/>
        <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
            <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.9"/>
            <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5"/>
            <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added a cleaned up version of your html

Comment: Thank you. I have modified code but getting error

availability 
Order Now (The value of availability is invalid. Valid values are: [http://schema.org/Discontinued
http://schema.org/InStock
|http://schema.org/InStoreOnly|
http://schema.org/LimitedAvailability|
http://schema.org/OnlineOnly|
http://schema.org/OutOfStock|
http://schema.org/PreOrder|
http://schema.org/PreSale|
http://schema.org/SoldOut])

Answer (score 0):

here is my exact code

```html
<!--about-who-block-->
<div class="browse-deploy-block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="browse-deploy-div">
            <div class="browse-deploy" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                <div class="browse-deploy-head">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="browse-deploy-head-h2">
                                <h2 itemprop="name">Product Name</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p itemprop="description">Description Description Description Description Description Description Description</p>
                    <link itemprop="image" content="/banner.jpg" alt="banner">
                    <meta itemprop="sku" content="SKU-Name">
                    <meta itemprop="mpn" content="MPN-Name">    <span itemprop="Brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
                            <meta itemprop="name" content="xxxx.com"/>
                            </span>
                    <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer" />
                    <meta itemprop="price" content="39" />
                    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
                    <meta itemprop="lowPrice" content="49" />
                    <meta itemprop="highPrice" content="249" />
                    <meta itemprop="offerCount" content="20" />
                </div>
                <!--browse-deploy-head-->
                <div class="browse-deploy-cont">
                    <div class="table-responsive" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Model</th>
                                <th>Starting At</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td itemprop="name">Intel Xeon E3-1220v6</td>
                                <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
                                <td><span class="start-amount">&euro; <span itemprop="price">49.00</span></span>
                                </td>
                                <td><a href="/cart.php?a=add&pid=819" class="get-free-quote"><span itemprop="availability" itemtype="http://schema.org/InStock">Order Now</span></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </span>
                <!--browse-deploy-cont-->   <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
                            <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.9"/>
                            <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="37" />
                            <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">
                            <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
                            </span>
                <span itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" />
                <meta itemprop="author" content="Author-name" />
                <meta itemprop="name" content="Author-name" />
                <meta itemprop="description" content="Review-description Review-description Review-description Review-description" /><span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" />
                <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.9" />
                <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5">
                <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
                </span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <!--browse-deploy-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using itemtype for the availability value is not valid. Try changing it to content.